# How to fetch data from database and display it in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I get data from a database using php and show it?

The database table has columns, labeled as `ID` & `Number`. ID is unique & fixed whereas Number is just a non-unique number. If someone visits
`http://example.com/show.php?ID=32`, and `show.php` should fetch the `Number` & display `"Your number is XXX”`

Please provide the code-samples.

Comment: Looks like the database has one table with two fields. Please clarify your question. Also, do you know how to connect to the database? and what database system is it (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)?

Comment: @Tash, He does specify `mysql` in the tags.

Comment: RobertPitt seems to have the right answer. I cannot vote here without registration, so I registerd to vote.

Comment: I am allowed to ask additional questions or do I need to open a new question?

Comment: each question requires you to create a new question, but remember to search before you ask as the chances are that it's already been asked

Comment: Thank you, I have tried search, the problem with search is that I cannot find the right answer, because my knowledge is not good enough to ask the right question. I think that is why I cannot find it.

Comment: Thank you. I just added it to

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091010/php-create-embed-image-from-database-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$db = mysql_connect("localhst","user","pass") or die("Database Error");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$db);

//Get ID from request
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;

//Check id is valid
if($id > 0)
{
    //Query the DB
    $resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $id);
    if($resource === false)
    {
        die("Database Error");
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($resource) == 0)
    {
        die("No User Exists");
    }

    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);

    echo "Hello User, your number is" . $user['number'];
}
```

This is very basic but should see you through.

Comment: Thank you! This is it! I have to register to give you a point. Strangely now I have 3 different users using the same email. I think it is a stackoverflow bug or I am being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

First get the id of the user(it may given while visiting or based on the details given while visiting)

Then write select query to the table which contains 'number' field.like

```
SELECT number FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID=IDFromtheuser;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT number from numberTable nt
JOIN idTable it ON  it.ID = nt.ID
WHERE it.ID = `your given id`
```

as i think your both tables are referenced with `id`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$username=""; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="multiple_del"; 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "root", "")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("multiple_del")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM test_mysql";


$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php


if($delete){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}


}

?>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



its my code but its not working and error are show in this code:-

<?php


if($delete){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}


}

?>

please help me.
```

Comment: Just add a sentence to explain. It will improve your answer.