# Using PHP, get data from MySQL and display it

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a CSV file with multiple books that are sorted in the format of Title, Price, Description on each line. Imported into the MySQL database I need a PHP script that can show the information when a title of a book is selected. That is a title caled "The Book" being a type of ID and the information on the same row being displayed where needed in a HTML template.

Any language being a solution to this problem would help, but I prefer PHP if possible.

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a site just to have other people write you code, you need to make an attempt yourself and any problems you then come into you can ask about in another question.

Comment: Already have my answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094552/get-variable-data-from-database-and-show-it-in-php

Comment: I already made an attempt myself. Did you not read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use orm if want do it really easy. If want to keep overhead low use php standard library